# mysqli prepared statement bind_param error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am having a problem with switching from `mysql_` in php to `mysqli_`. I wrote this based on the PHP documentation but I keep getting an error:

```
if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE MATCH(DESCRIPTION) AGAINST ('?') LIMIT $start, $limit")) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $search);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($vlink, $ilink, $des, $rating, $site);
    }
```

It says:

> mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement".

However I only have one question mark so I do not see why it is not working

Comment: Remove the quotes for the question mark.

Comment: -.- I completely overlooked that I copied the statement from the mysql_ statement and just added a question mark lol

Comment: Problem solved then. `Another happy ending` ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well what you're doing is essentially calling `?` as `'?'`, which turns it into a string. So what you need to do is get rid of that so this is what you do

```
SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE MATCH(DESCRIPTION) AGAINST (?) LIMIT $start, $limit"
```